# How to update a column in postgresql using two servers?

Tags: postgresql

I have a local table with many fields. I need to update the values on a different server(same db structure) just for one column. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

have yout tried dblink?

```
SELECT INTO AFFECTED_ROW_COUNT_STRING 
DBLINK_EXEC('host=localhost  port=5432 dbname=DBNAME user=USERNAME password=PASSWORD', 
'UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = VALUE ');
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to return the changed column in the results and to apply the changes on both servers.

```
create table test123 {
    id serial primary key,
    myvalue int4
};
```

Assume, you have rows from 1 to 100 in both tables on both servers. This statement updates your rows, and produces a single string result with update statements you can do on the other server also.

```
update test123 set myvalue = rand() 
returning 'UPDATE test123 SET myvalue='||test123||' WHERE id='||id||';';
```

PS: Untested, but should work with minor syntax fixes.